# Convert Chrome history date/time stamp to readable format

Tags: python, macos, datetime, google-chrome

I originally posted this question looking for an answer with using python, got some good help, but have still not been able to find a solution. I have a script running on OS X 10.5 client machines that captures internet browsing history (required as part of my sys admin duties in a US public school). Firefox 3.x stores history in a sqlite db, and I have figured out how to get that info out using python/sqlite3. Firefox 3.x uses a conventional unixtimestamp to mark visits and that is not difficult to convert... Chrome also stores browser history in a sqlite db, but its timestamp is formatted as the number of microseconds since January, 1601. I'd like to figure this out using python, but as far as I know, the sqlite3 module doesn't support that UTC format. Is there another tool out there to convert Chrome timestamps to a human readable format?

Comment: Very helpful.  How did you find out that the Google Chrome timestamps are the number of microseconds since January, 1601?

Comment: Chrome SQLite format, including the Jan 1601, is discussed in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/c4lnssuNAFI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#module-datetime) module.  For example, if the number of microseconds in questions is 10**16:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(1601, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=1e16)
datetime.datetime(1917, 11, 21, 17, 46, 40)
>>> _.isoformat()
'1917-11-21T17:46:40'
```

this tells you it was just past a quarter to 6pm of November 21, 1917.  You can format `datetime` objects in any way you want thanks to their `strftime` method, of course.  If you also need to apply timezones (other than the UTC you start with), look at third-party module [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Bash

```
  $ date -ud @$[13315808702856828/10**6-11644473600] +"%F %T %Z"
    2022-12-18 03:45:02 UTC
  $ printf '%(%FT %T %z)T\n' $[13315808702856828/10**6-11644473600]
    2022-12-17 T19:45:02 -0800
```

Perl

```
$ echo ".. 13315808702856828 .." |\
    perl -MPOSIX -pe 's!\b(1\d{16})\b!strftime(q/%F/,gmtime($1/1e6-11644473600))!e'
.. 2022-12-17 ..
```