# WebKit/Chrome Timestamp convert into Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix-timestamp, epoch

How to convert WebKit/Chrome Timestamp into Ruby/Rails.

Here is the timestamp data from Chrome excel `13130755192116927` but how I convert into the human-readable format using Ruby/Rails.

I have found some examples like [`How to convert a unix timestamp (seconds since epoch) to Ruby DateTime?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816365/how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-seconds-since-epoch-to-ruby-datetime) but this data length is 13 & my data length is 17.

How I achieve that as like this [WebKit/Chrome Timestamp Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/webkit).

```
GMT: Sunday, February 5, 2017 7:59:52 AM
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193820/convert-chrome-history-date-time-stamp-to-readable-format)

> Google timestamp is formatted as the number of microseconds since
>   January, 1601

So here an Ruby example :

```
require 'date'

chrome_timestamp = 13130755192116927

# Get the January 1601 unixepoch
since_epoch = DateTime.new(1601,1,1).to_time.to_i

# Transfrom Chrome timestamp to seconds and add 1601 epoch
final_epoch = (chrome_timestamp / 1000000) + since_epoch

# Print DateTime
date = DateTime.strptime(final_epoch.to_s, '%s')

# without formating
puts date
=> '2017-02-05T07:59:52+00:00'

# with formating
puts date.strftime('%A, %B %-d, %Y %-I:%M:%S %p')
=> 'Sunday, February 5, 2017 7:59:52 AM'
```

Comment: Could you suggest me please how I get as like this `Sunday, February 5, 2017 7:59:52 AM`

Comment: In the https://www.epochconverter.com/webkit showing `7:59:52 AM` but in your code, it's showing `07:50:31+00:00`, please advise

Comment: @user9769384 Try this `DateTime.strptime(final_epoch.to_s, '%s').strftime("%A, %B %-d, %Y %-l:%M:%S %p")`. Basically I just added a method that converts it to your desired format.

Comment: Fixed, I was using Date.new instead of DateTime.new, now it return the correct date and i added formating example

Comment: Thanks & I will check this soon

Comment: OMG! you can & finally I passed the complexity

Comment: It was my first post about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436374/convert-to-ruby-code-based-on-python-code-snippet